# Why is AsyncTask behaving sporadically?

Tags: android, multithreading, parsing, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have an asynctask that I am using to parse JSON and XML data during my ocCreate method.  The problem is that the Async Task only  finishes it's "do in background" work once out of every ten times.  When it fails to complete it's background work, the app crashes due to variables the weren't instantiated in the background process and are referenced in post-execute.  This is very strange, because when the AsyncTask finishes it background work everythig works fine.  Any help is greatly appreciated

My Code

```
 private class LoadingData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

            //TWITTER
            //Parses Twitter XML with no problem...

publishProgress(15,1);

//SPOT GOLD AND SILVER

                try{
                    GoldSpotPriceReader.feed = "http://feed43.com/437361835043234.xml";//Gold
                    GoldSpotPriceReader.getLatestRssFeed();
                    livespotgold=GoldSpotPriceReader.spotprice;
                    storedspotgold=livespotgold;

                    SilverSpotPriceReader.feed = "http://feed43.com/824383110654537.xml";//Silver
                    SilverSpotPriceReader.getLatestRssFeed();
                    livespotsilver=SilverSpotPriceReader.spotprice;
                    storedspotsilver=livespotsilver;
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){    
                    Log.e("Spot Price Initial", "Spot Price Format Error "+e.toString());
                } 
//AsyncTask Usually Ends Here For No Particular Reason.
    //And doesn't finish background work...                 
publishProgress(30,2);

//More background work...           

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog (MyActivity.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        //dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setMessage("Fetching Latest News");          
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.show();

        finddealer = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvFindDealer);
        finddealer.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        Touchy tango = new Touchy();
        overlayList = finddealer.getOverlays();
        overlayList.add(tango);
        compass = new MyLocationOverlay(MyActivity.this, finddealer);
        overlayList.add(compass);
        controller = finddealer.getController();
        controller.setZoom(11);

        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 300000, 5000, MyActivity.this);
        crit = new Criteria();
        towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

        delta = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin_48);
        zulu = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        switch (progress[1])
        {
            case 1:
                dialog.setMessage("Acquiring  Prices...");
                break;
            case 2:
                dialog.setMessage("Acquiring  Rates...");
                break;
            case 3:
                dialog.setMessage("Acquiring More Rates...");
                break;
            case 4:
                dialog.setMessage("Pinpointing Your Location...");
                break;
            case 5:
                dialog.setMessage("Locating Nearest  Dealers...");
                break;
            case 6:
                dialog.setMessage("Calculating Shortest Routes...");
                break;
            case 7:
                dialog.setMessage("Mapping  Dealers...");
                break;
            case 8:
                dialog.setMessage("Finalizing...");
                break;
        }
    }               

  @Override     
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {       
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.setProgress(100);
        dialog.setMessage("Load Complete.");
        dialog.dismiss();

 //Other UIthread variables...
}
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace of the error?

Comment: The error is a basic NullPointer.  A variable that I instantiate later in he background process is never instantiated because the Async stops prior.  I refer the the variable in post execute and the app crashes.  i need to find out why my Async just stops unexpectedly.

Comment: I see in your doInBackground() you have a try/catch block which I assume wraps the entire method... is an exception ever caught there? Also, how many AsyncTasks are you trying to fire at once, just one?

Comment: that try line was a typo.  I'm only firing one Async though.  I tried cleaning my project also but it didn't help.

Comment: I would try surrounding the code in doInBackground() with a try/catch and log any exceptions, that may tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: Still no luck surrounding entire background with try/catch.  It crashed with same NullPointer and didn't send an error as to why async stopped midway through background process

Comment: Which variable is it that is thrown the null pointer exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had  similar situation before with my AsyncTask.  the problem was that I was catching an exception and trying to throw a toast without a handler and runnable.  So make sure you not trying to do anything on the UIThread within do-in-background process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in your `.getLatestRssFeed()` methods, since these are your network connection functions. I can not see your code for those, but I assume you are probably spawning a new thread in those to access the feed, yet your `AsyncTask` continues on and tries to assign the value to `liveSpotSilver` and `Gold`, however they haven't been set yet. You need to fix this first, then see if you still have a problem.

Even if this is not the problem, 9 times out of 10, an `AsyncTask` will not finish if you encounter a Network error and it hangs, **the network connection is the problem**. If you are spawning new threads in `SilverSpotPriceReader` and `Gold...`, you shouldn't need to since you are already doing the work asynchronously.  You can debug better by catching the exceptions thrown as suggested by others.